# How to implement QRScanner with timer in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am using below function to get the `metadataObject` and post it to server.

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
```

Now I want to add a Timer (counter) to the QR-Scanner so when the user starts scanning the QR-Code ,Timer starts counting down (from 3) and when it reaches `0` the rest of the code (posting metadata to server) runs.

I did put `self.setTimer()` inside the function above, but `captureSession.stop()` gets called immediately and Scanner doesn't wait for the Timer to finish counting.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer.
I use a flag so that the `captureOutput` function gets called once (this way `self.setTimer()` does not get called several times).

Then used

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3, execute: {
```

to stop the `captureSession` and then execute the rest of the code (posting metadata to server) after 3second when the timer is done counting down.

So now the scanner runs and if it detects a `QR-Code` the timer starts running and the rest of the code runs after 3secs.